# Tableau Convert Date to first date of the month

Tags: tableau-desktop

How can I convert any date to first of the month in tableau while retaining month as 2 digits and
format as date?

I have tried

```
INT("01" + "-" + STR(MONTH([Date])) + "-" + STR(YEAR(Date))) which returns month as single digit
```

| Date | Converted Date |
| --- | --- |
| 9/01/2020 | 1/01/2020 |
| 10/01/2020 | 1/01/2020 |
| 5/03/2021 | 1/03/2021 |
| 12/03/2021 | 1/03/2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a calculated field like this:

```
MAKEDATE(YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date]),1)
```

If you're using a live connection, it all depends on the source you're connecting to.

You can also try:

```
date(
right('0'+str(month([Order Date])),2)
+
'01'
+
str(year([Order Date]))
)
```

Just remember to right-click your CF --> Default Properties --> Date Format

You should get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Fabio but I dont think it will work on Live connection. Makedate works with extract only. Any other alternative?

Comment: Ok, maybe add all the information in the question, such as you need something that must run on live connection.

Comment: I've updated the answer providing another version of the CF, but please specify the source you're live connecting to.